# want to over-write or manipulate page size of PDF

Tags: python, pdf, metadata, inkscape

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X5kb.png)

This is a snapshot for reference, here and I want to resize the default size of the PDF that I have marked with a rectangle box. I can do it manually with any media editor but I want to do it with Python or with command-line with the help of the editor like Inkscape.